# Delphi: How to reference an array from within a class

Tags: arrays, class, delphi

I work with arrays and have tested the functionality within the context of a class, like:

```
Ttest   = class
 values : array of integer;
 procedure doStuff;
end;
```

The methods, like `doStuff` all operate on the values array without the need to pass the array as a parameter. This suits me and it is fast.
Now I want to use this class to work with an external array, like `Ttest.create(myValues)` In the constructor I could copy `myValues` to the internal `values` but that would be quite a waste and moreover, at the end the copy would have to be reversed to pass the updated values back.
My question is how can I extend this class so that it can efficiently work with an external array. In pseudo code like this:

```
constructor create(var myValues : array of integer);
begin
  address of values := address of myValues;
  doSTuff;
end;
```

Comment: In Delphi, [dynamic arrays](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays) are reference types, so `A := B` will not make a copy of the `B` array, but only increase its reference count. However, please notice that in your second example, `array of Integer` is not a dynamic array parameter but an [open array parameter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Open_Array_Parameters). In any case, probably the best solution is to let your procs take arguments (`var` arguments if they need to reallocate the array).

Comment: And if you don't want/need open arrays, change everything from `Array of Integer` to i.e. `TIntegerArray` - if that shouldn't exist you can simply define it thru `type TIntegerArray= Array of Integer` (looks obvious, but is needed for the compiler to unambiguously understand what you want).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Lesson 1

In Delphi, [dynamic arrays](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays) are reference types. A variable of dynamic array type contains only a pointer to the actual dynamic array heap object, and in an assignment,

```
A := B
```

where `A` and `B` are dynamic arrays of the same type, the dynamic array heap object isn't copied. The only thing that happens is that `A` and `B` will point to the same dynamic array heap object (that is, the 32- or 64-bit `B` pointer is copied to `A`) and that the [reference count](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Internal_Data_Formats_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Array_Types) of the heap object is increased by 1.

## Lesson 2

When you write

```
constructor Create(var AValues: array of Integer);
```

you need to realise that this, despite the appearance, isn't a dynamic array parameter, but an [open array parameter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Open_Array_Parameters).

If you explicitly want a dynamic array parameter, you need to use such a type explicitly:

```
constructor Create(AValues: TArray<Integer>);
```

By definition, `TArray<Integer> = array of Integer` is a dynamic array of `Integer`s.

Please note that the language only has two *types* of arrays – static and dynamic; the open array concept is only about function parameters.

If you want to work with dynamic arrays, taking advantage of their nature as reference types, I would suggest you use dynamic array parameters. Then the only thing that is passed to the function (the constructor in this case) is the pointer to the heap object. And the heap object's reference count is increased, of course.

## Lesson 3 – An example

```pascal
var
  Arr: TArray<Integer>;

procedure Test(A: TArray<Integer>);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := Low(A) to High(A) do
    A[i] := 2*A[i];
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin

  SetLength(Arr, 10);
  for i := 0 to High(Arr) do
    Arr[i] := i;

  Test(Arr);

  for i := 0 to High(Arr) do
    ShowMessage(Arr[i].ToString);

end;
```

After `SetLength`, `Arr` points to a dynamic array heap object of reference count 1. You can see it in your RAM (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and goto `Arr[0]`). When you enter `Test`, the reference count is increased to 2 because both `Arr` and `A` refer to it. When you leave `Test`, the reference count is reduced back to 1 because `A` goes out of scope: now again only `Arr` refers to it.

## Lesson 4

Now, a “gotcha”: if you change the number of elements of a dynamic array, it needs to be reallocated (*). Hence, a new dynamic array heap object is created with a reference count of 1, and the old object has its reference count decreased by 1 (and removed if it becomes zero).

Thus, while the previous example works as expected, the following will not:

```pascal
var
  Arr: TArray<Integer>;

procedure Test(A: TArray<Integer>);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(A, 5);
  for i := Low(A) to High(A) do
    A[i] := 2*A[i];
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin

  SetLength(Arr, 10);
  for i := 0 to High(Arr) do
    Arr[i] := i;

  Test(Arr);

  for i := 0 to High(Arr) do
    ShowMessage(Arr[i].ToString);

end;
```

The `SetLength` will create a new dynamic array heap object with refcount 1 and copy half of the old array into this, put the new address in the local `A` parameter, and `Test` will transform this new array, not touching the old one which the global `Arr` variable points to. The reference count of the original heap object is decreased by one.

However, if you use a `var` parameter,

```pascal
procedure Test(var A: TArray<Integer>);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(A, 5);
  for i := Low(A) to High(A) do
    A[i] := 2*A[i];
end;
```

it will work as before. This effectively works with `Arr`. If we had increased the number of elements, the array would probably have been reallocated and the global `Arr` variable would have been updated with the new address.

## Conclusion

As long as you don't need to reallocate the memory (change the number of elements), Delphi already gives you what you want, because dynamic arrays are reference types. If you do need to reallocate, at least now you know enough of the technical details in order to reason about it.

**Update:** Hence, the suggestion is to do

```pascal
type
  TTest = class
    FData: TArray<Integer>;
    constructor Create(AData: TArray<Integer>);
    procedure Enlarge;
    procedure Shrink;
    procedure ShowSum;
  end;

{ TTest }

constructor TTest.Create(AData: TArray<Integer>);
begin
  FData := AData; // will NOT copy the array, since dynamic arrays are reference types
end;

procedure TTest.Enlarge;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to High(FData) do
    FData[i] := 2*FData[i];
end;

procedure TTest.ShowSum;
var
  s: Integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  s := 0;
  for i := 0 to High(FData) do
    Inc(s, FData[i]);
  ShowMessage(s.ToString);
end;

procedure TTest.Shrink;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to High(FData) do
    FData[i] := FData[i] div 2;
end;
```

To test it:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyArray: TArray<Integer>;
  t: TTest;
begin

  MyArray := [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  t := TTest.Create(MyArray);
  try
    t.ShowSum;
    t.Enlarge;
    t.ShowSum;
    t.Shrink;
    t.ShowSum;
  finally
    t.Free;
  end;

end;
```

## Footnotes

- If you (1) decrease the number of elements and (2) the reference count is 1, typically the data isn't moved in memory. If the reference count is > 1, the data is always moved, because [`SetLength`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SetLength) guarantees that the reference count of its argument is `1` when it returns.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally wrote a short book. :/

Comment: It can't hurt, as the difference between `Array of` variables and parameters needs time and repeated experiences to be understood with all their advantages and disadvantages. Thumb of rule for me is: "never use `Array of` except for the "multiple parameters at once" case.

Comment: @Amigo I don't know what "multiple parameters at once" means, but my rule is to use open arrays where possible since it means that you can pass the widest range of arguments. You can pass both dynamic and fixed length arrays.

Comment: This answer assumes the OP has control over the alloaction of the array and can make it be a dynamic array to begin with. But if the array comes from a 3rd party library, for instance, then the array will have to be passed around using a raw pointer instead, and reference counting won't apply. Just saying...

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Very good point. I based my hypothesis on the OP's `values : array of integer` (which is a Delphi dynamic array), but the real code might indeed has some other source of the array. But without reference counting, it only becomes simpler, at least conceptually.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan In cases like `printf( 'at %s with %d', [name, 3.1415] )` - in this case with `Array of Const`. Where you would want to have a function with an unknown amount of parameters.

Comment: If I use `constructor create(myValues : TintegerArray);` the access will be limited to (descendents of) arrays of that type. Whereas `constructor create(myValues : array of integer)` will make the function more versatile. (@DavidHeffeman's comment.) I want it be useful to others so  a dynamic array has my preference. Other than 'pass the array as argument to all methods' I have not recognized a suitable answer. @RemyLebeau can you explain how you would pass an array as a raw pointer and then treat it inside the methods as an indexed array. As. in `move(values[k],temp[0],n*sizeof(integer))'.

Comment: @user3212191: (1) It will be limited to `TIntegerArray` (presumably defined as `array of Integer`, so dynamic array of integers). There are no "descendants" of non-class types. (2) That's an open array parameter. It will *copy the entire array* and might even lead to stack overflows as warned in the docs. Use `const` to solve that. But then you cannot modify the elements! So use `var`. (3) "so a dynamic array has my preference" Seems like you mean "open arrays", not "dynamic arrays". (4) My idea, as written implicitly in the A, is that the class has a field `FData: TArray<Integer>;` ...

Comment: ...and the constructor sets this: `FData := AData`. Then you can access this very same array from all your functions and procedures in the class.

Comment: I have updated the answer to be more explicit.

Comment: If you don't want to use dynamic arrays, but raw memory, you need to understand how to allocate and free heap memory. Then you only need to pass (pointer, size) pairs to functions. To use array notation on a pointer, you need to use the [`POINTERMATH`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Pointer_Math_(Delphi)) directive when you declare the pointer type.

Comment: Also notice that if you insist on using an open array parameter, I don't think you can save it in `FData` without making a full copy of the array.

Comment: @user3212191 "*Whereas `constructor create(myValues : array of integer)` will make the function more versatile*" - yes, however then something like `FData := AData` will not work, you would have no choice but to make a full copy of the array.  Whereas `constructor create(myValues : TintegerArray)` can leverage reference counting of the array to avoid making a copy (at least until the array is modified).

Comment: @user3212191 The thing that you need to understand is that if you declare one dynamic array like `Arr1: Array of Integer;` and another `Arr2: Array of Integer;` Delphi does not consider these two arrays to be of the same type. So if you later write `Arr2 := Arr1;` Delphi will create compilation error `E2008 Incompatible types`. So in order for you to operate on same array in multiple functions/procedures/classes all of them should be declaring it as same type. In your example that would be `TIntegerArray` as it was already suggested.

Comment: @SilverWarior: You mean "dynamic array". Also, if the OP is using a modern version of Delphi (2009+ IIRC), it is better to use `TArray<Integer>`.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Thanks for correcting me. I have edited my comment.